# How to check network connection with cURL

Tags: c++, linux, curl

I have a linux based embedded system and take snapshots from an ip camera using cURL library.

My camera provides some CGI functions and one of them is for taking image snapshot.

After invoking dedicated CGI function camera sends taken picture as response successfully.

I save cameras response as a jpg file and everything works fine so far.

But when the network connection is broken my code produces a zero sized jpg file.

I removed zero sized images but it will be better not saving image in case of curl_easy_perform(curl) call returns error.

is it possible disabling saving in case of error in cURL?

```
  const int maxNumberOfImages = 20;
  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode result;
  FILE *CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION_FILE;
  bool flag = true;

  string url = "http://admin:1234@";//needs refactory
  url.append(ip);
  url.append(":80/snapshot.jpg");
  DEBUG_PRINT(url);

  char actionDate[20];
  time_t now = time(NULL);
  strftime(actionDate, 20, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", localtime(&now));

  char *directory = "/root/rootfs_frequent_rw/snapshots/";

  string fileName = directory;
  fileName.append(cam_name);
  fileName.append("___");
  fileName.append(actionDate);
  fileName.append(".jpg");

  createDirectoryIfNotExist(directory);

  curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
  curl = curl_easy_init();
  CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION_FILE = fopen(fileName.c_str(), "wb");

  if(curl) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION_FILE);
    result = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    if(result != CURLE_OK){
        DEBUG_PRINT("ERROR\n");
        flag = false;
    }
    else
        DEBUG_PRINT("SUCCESS\n");
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  }

  fclose(CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION_FILE);
  cx based embedded system and taking snapshots from an ip camera. url_global_cleanup();

  isFileEmpty(fileName.c_str()); //if file is zero sized delete it.

  if(flag)
        return ReturnValue::return_success;
  return ReturnValue::return_operation_failed;
```

Comment: The file is already created by the `fopen()` here: `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION_FILE = fopen(fileName.c_str(), "wb");`. So the problem is out of the scope of the CURL library. An option would be, to save the data into a memory buffer and subsequently save it to a file when it looks sane.

Comment: Use a consistent naming style with proper case for identifiers. While there are few commonly accepted general rules, all-uppercase identifiers like `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION_FILE` are expected to only be macros or enum-constants. And C is not C++ is not C. Do not add unrelated tags.

Answer (score 1):

i solved the problem by using CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION option. After changing an example code (getinmemory) from cURL documentation i got the following code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <curl/curl.h>

struct MemoryStruct {
  char *memory;
  size_t size;
};

static size_t WriteMemoryCallback(void *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp)
{
  size_t realsize = size * nmemb;
  struct MemoryStruct *mem = (struct MemoryStruct *)userp;

  mem->memory = realloc(mem->memory, mem->size + realsize + 1);
  if(mem->memory == NULL) {
    /* out of memory! */ 
    printf("not enough memory (realloc returned NULL)\n");
    return 0;
  }

  memcpy(&(mem->memory[mem->size]), contents, realsize);
  mem->size += realsize;
  mem->memory[mem->size] = 0;

  return realsize;
}

int main(void)
{
  CURL *curl_handle;
  CURLcode res;
  FILE *pFile;
  struct MemoryStruct chunk;

  chunk.memory = malloc(1);  /* will be grown as needed by the realloc above */ 
  chunk.size = 0;    /* no data at this point */ 

  curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

  /* init the curl session */ 
  curl_handle = curl_easy_init();

  /* specify URL to get */ 
  curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, "http://admin:1234@10.108.67.235:80/snapshot.jpg");

  /* send all data to this function  */ 
  curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteMemoryCallback);

  /* we pass our 'chunk' struct to the callback function */ 
  curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, (void *)&chunk);

  /* some servers don't like requests that are made without a user-agent
     field, so we provide one */ 
  curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "libcurl-agent/1.0");

  curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1L);
  /* get it! */ 
  res = curl_easy_perform(curl_handle);

  /* check for errors */ 
  if(res != CURLE_OK) {
    fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n", curl_easy_strerror(res));
  }
  else {
    /*
     * Now, our chunk.memory points to a memory block that is chunk.size
     * bytes big and contains the remote file.
     *
     * Do something nice with it!
     */ 

    printf("%lu bytes retrieved\n", (long)chunk.size);

    pFile = fopen("test.jpg", "wb");

    fwrite(chunk.memory, sizeof(char), (long)chunk.size, pFile);

    fclose(pFile);
  }

  /* cleanup curl stuff */ 
  curl_easy_cleanup(curl_handle);

  free(chunk.memory);

  /* we're done with libcurl, so clean it up */ 
  curl_global_cleanup();

  return 0;
}
```